# HTML Confirming selection with button

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to make a simple HTML page that allows you to select the option either copy, lower case or upper case, which respectively copy  into text2, change the text to uppercase or to lowercase, and select the choice on click.
Could anyone take a look at my code?

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
function f(){
  if(document.getElementById("copy")) 
    document.getElementById("modifiedForm").value = document.getElementById("ogForm").value;
  if(document.getElementById("upper"))
    document.getElementById("modifiedForm").value = document.getElementById("ogForm").value.toUpperCase();
  if(document.getElementById("lower"))
    document.getElementById("modifiedForm").value = document.getElementById("ogForm").value.toLowerCase();
}
</script>
<form name='form1' >
<select size='3' name='sel1' > <!--  onchange='f();'>  -->
<option id="copy">  copy       </option>
<option id="upper"> upper case </option>
<option id="lower"> lower case </option>
</select>
<input type='text1' id='ogForm' placeholder="type here" >
<input type='text2' id='modifiedForm'>
<input type='button' id='confirm' value='confirm' onclick='f()'>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to check which was the element that was selected as an option of the `select` element.

You need the value of the `select` which was selected as an option.

**HTML**

```
<select size='3' name='sel1' id="mySelect"> 
   <option value="copy">  copy       </option>
   <option value="upper"> upper case </option>
   <option value="lower"> lower case </option>
```

**JS**

```
function f() {
     var selectedValue = document.getElementById("mySelect").value;

     if(selectedValue === 'copy') {

     ....
```

Comment: Is selectedValue in the if condition the same as the variable declared above?